# I want to convert Integer into hh:mm:ss format in Informix database

Tags: sql, informix

`SELECT MAX(longestwaitduration) AS MaxWaitD from myTable;`

Here, Column `longestwaitduration` is `Integer` in which miliseconds stored and the database is Informix version 11+.

Comment: Do you want the fractional seconds reported, truncated or rounded?

Comment: Truncated or rounded.. Both work for me

Answer (score 1):

Here's a SELECT statement that works on a table `millitimes` with an INTEGER column `milliseconds`:

```
SELECT milliseconds,
       (milliseconds / 1000) AS seconds_f3,
       TRUNC(milliseconds/1000) AS tr_seconds,
       ROUND(milliseconds/1000) AS ro_seconds,
       TRUNC(milliseconds/1000) UNITS SECOND AS tr_iv_s9,
       ROUND(milliseconds/1000) UNITS SECOND AS ro_iv_s9,
       CAST(TRUNC(milliseconds/1000) UNITS SECOND AS INTERVAL HOUR(9) TO SECOND) AS tr_iv_hs,
       CAST(ROUND(milliseconds/1000) UNITS SECOND AS INTERVAL HOUR(9) TO SECOND) AS rd_iv_hs,
       (milliseconds/1000) UNITS FRACTION(3) AS iv_s9f3,
       CAST((milliseconds/1000) UNITS FRACTION(3) AS INTERVAL HOUR(9) TO FRACTION(3)) AS iv_h2f3
  FROM millitimes
 ORDER BY milliseconds;
```

This shows how I progressed towards a solution.

The key tricks are:

1. using UNITS SECOND or UNITS FRACTION(3) to convert a number into an interval, and then
2. casting the result to the INTERVAL type you want.  You could use INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND or INTERVAL DAY(9) TO FRACTION(3) or similar if you wanted.

Sample data and schema.

The times are random values — in two sequences. The first six were generated using a uniform distribution between 0 and 86,400,000 (the number of milliseconds in a day). The remainder of the values were generated using a 'uniform logarithm' algorithm, so the logarithm of the time was generated uniformly for the range 1000 milliseconds to 864,000,000 milliseconds (10 days) and then converted back to a value.  It gives an emphasis on smaller values while covering big values too.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE millitimes (milliseconds INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO millitimes VALUES(65284606);
INSERT INTO millitimes VALUES(40498249);
INSERT INTO millitimes VALUES(83967419);
INSERT INTO millitimes VALUES(35819561);
INSERT INTO millitimes VALUES(72919126);
INSERT INTO millitimes VALUES(43567311);

INSERT INTO millitimes VALUES(75242);
INSERT INTO millitimes VALUES(13043053);
INSERT INTO millitimes VALUES(48569485);
INSERT INTO millitimes VALUES(14161761);
INSERT INTO millitimes VALUES(355773248);
INSERT INTO millitimes VALUES(2599);
INSERT INTO millitimes VALUES(3038);
INSERT INTO millitimes VALUES(359329);
INSERT INTO millitimes VALUES(484870033);
INSERT INTO millitimes VALUES(254664);
INSERT INTO millitimes VALUES(248989810);
INSERT INTO millitimes VALUES(87865);
INSERT INTO millitimes VALUES(2225346);
INSERT INTO millitimes VALUES(2779735);
INSERT INTO millitimes VALUES(1889026);
INSERT INTO millitimes VALUES(48921224);
INSERT INTO millitimes VALUES(43920528);
INSERT INTO millitimes VALUES(321290);
INSERT INTO millitimes VALUES(108176);
INSERT INTO millitimes VALUES(32854);
```

Sample output:

| milliseconds | seconds_f3 | tr_seconds | ro_seconds | tr_iv_s9 | ro_iv_s9 | tr_iv_hs | rd_iv_hs | iv_s9f3 | iv_h2f3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INTEGER | DECIMAL(20) | DECIMAL(32,0) | DECIMAL(32,0) | INTERVAL SECOND(9) TO SECOND | INTERVAL SECOND(9) TO SECOND | INTERVAL HOUR(9) TO SECOND | INTERVAL HOUR(9) TO SECOND | INTERVAL SECOND(9) TO FRACTION(3) | INTERVAL HOUR(9) TO FRACTION(3) |
| 2599 | 2.599 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 0:00:02 | 0:00:03 | 2.599 | 0:00:02.599 |
| 3038 | 3.038 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 0:00:03 | 0:00:03 | 3.038 | 0:00:03.038 |
| 32854 | 32.854 | 32 | 33 | 32 | 33 | 0:00:32 | 0:00:33 | 32.854 | 0:00:32.854 |
| 75242 | 75.242 | 75 | 75 | 75 | 75 | 0:01:15 | 0:01:15 | 75.242 | 0:01:15.242 |
| 87865 | 87.865 | 87 | 88 | 87 | 88 | 0:01:27 | 0:01:28 | 87.865 | 0:01:27.865 |
| 108176 | 108.176 | 108 | 108 | 108 | 108 | 0:01:48 | 0:01:48 | 108.176 | 0:01:48.176 |
| 254664 | 254.664 | 254 | 255 | 254 | 255 | 0:04:14 | 0:04:15 | 254.664 | 0:04:14.664 |
| 321290 | 321.29 | 321 | 321 | 321 | 321 | 0:05:21 | 0:05:21 | 321.290 | 0:05:21.290 |
| 359329 | 359.329 | 359 | 359 | 359 | 359 | 0:05:59 | 0:05:59 | 359.329 | 0:05:59.329 |
| 1889026 | 1889.026 | 1889 | 1889 | 1889 | 1889 | 0:31:29 | 0:31:29 | 1889.026 | 0:31:29.026 |
| 2225346 | 2225.346 | 2225 | 2225 | 2225 | 2225 | 0:37:05 | 0:37:05 | 2225.346 | 0:37:05.346 |
| 2779735 | 2779.735 | 2779 | 2780 | 2779 | 2780 | 0:46:19 | 0:46:20 | 2779.735 | 0:46:19.735 |
| 13043053 | 13043.053 | 13043 | 13043 | 13043 | 13043 | 3:37:23 | 3:37:23 | 13043.053 | 3:37:23.053 |
| 14161761 | 14161.761 | 14161 | 14162 | 14161 | 14162 | 3:56:01 | 3:56:02 | 14161.761 | 3:56:01.761 |
| 35819561 | 35819.561 | 35819 | 35820 | 35819 | 35820 | 9:56:59 | 9:57:00 | 35819.561 | 9:56:59.561 |
| 40498249 | 40498.249 | 40498 | 40498 | 40498 | 40498 | 11:14:58 | 11:14:58 | 40498.249 | 11:14:58.249 |
| 43567311 | 43567.311 | 43567 | 43567 | 43567 | 43567 | 12:06:07 | 12:06:07 | 43567.311 | 12:06:07.311 |
| 43920528 | 43920.528 | 43920 | 43921 | 43920 | 43921 | 12:12:00 | 12:12:01 | 43920.528 | 12:12:00.528 |
| 48569485 | 48569.485 | 48569 | 48569 | 48569 | 48569 | 13:29:29 | 13:29:29 | 48569.485 | 13:29:29.485 |
| 48921224 | 48921.224 | 48921 | 48921 | 48921 | 48921 | 13:35:21 | 13:35:21 | 48921.224 | 13:35:21.224 |
| 65284606 | 65284.606 | 65284 | 65285 | 65284 | 65285 | 18:08:04 | 18:08:05 | 65284.606 | 18:08:04.606 |
| 72919126 | 72919.126 | 72919 | 72919 | 72919 | 72919 | 20:15:19 | 20:15:19 | 72919.126 | 20:15:19.126 |
| 83967419 | 83967.419 | 83967 | 83967 | 83967 | 83967 | 23:19:27 | 23:19:27 | 83967.419 | 23:19:27.419 |
| 248989810 | 248989.81 | 248989 | 248990 | 248989 | 248990 | 69:09:49 | 69:09:50 | 248989.810 | 69:09:49.810 |
| 355773248 | 355773.248 | 355773 | 355773 | 355773 | 355773 | 98:49:33 | 98:49:33 | 355773.248 | 98:49:33.248 |
| 484870033 | 484870.033 | 484870 | 484870 | 484870 | 484870 | 134:41:10 | 134:41:10 | 484870.033 | 134:41:10.033 |